# Web view virtual keyboard handling in android

Tags: android, android-webview, virtual-keyboard

I have a text box in web view, when tap that text box default android keyboard up to enter the text, with GO button in virtual keyboard. I need to handle that GO button press in android.I tried with KeyUp and KeyDown function in default activity , but it won`t trigger.

How to handle that virtual keyboard in android web view (android 2.2).